# Azure SQL Server Admin v/s Regular User

Tags: azure, server, admin, portal

Currently, I am a server admin on an Azure SQL server.  When I create an azure function app and connect to a database (on the server) I have to specify a sql connection string from the app. The connection string will use my username and password.

I want to change this so that the server admin is an active directory group (development group or something).  Microsoft support told me I can not set a password to an active directory group.  How do I create the connection string without a password? Or do I have to create an office 365 account with a development identity so I can set a development user and development password?

In Sql server management (ssms), the server admin is listed under the security directory.  I have been using the server admin username and password to connect to the database from azure function apps.

Now I created a user called Development on ssms like this:

> USE CompanyDatabase
>   CREATE LOGIN Development 
>     WITH PASSWORD = 'password';
>   GO

I tried using the development login as parameters in my connection string and got this error:

Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation. .Net SqlClient Data Provider: The server principal "Development" is not able to access the database

Comment: Not sure what you're asking. You say you have access to an "Azure server" - are you referring to a VM? Also, where are you setting this connection string? Please edit your question to be more clear. Right now, this question is unclear, and also sounding a bit like a better fit for ServerFault (I don't have a sense for how this is a programming question yet).

Answer (score 1):

You have only created a LOGIN so far with the command that you mentioned.

Next step is to create the USER which will use this login and then assign some permissions to that user. I have given an example with db_datawriter, but you can choose something different like db_datareader or db_owner etc.

> CREATE USER [Development] FROM LOGIN [Development]
>
> EXEC sp_addrolemember 'db_datawriter', 'Development';

Also on a side note, Azure SQL Database supports contained database user model, where you don't need to create a server level login first and then a user based on it, instead you directly create a user which is contained only in that database. There are some pros and cons to using this model. You can get more information about it here -

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/security/contained-database-users-making-your-database-portable?view=sql-server-2017

Comment: @Dtjin did the solution work for you? or still facing issues accessing database as Development user?

Comment: Hi! Sorry for the late reply and thank you for your help.

I created the login on the server level so master. After I assign a user to the login and ran the sp_addrolemember command I get this error:

Cannot alter the role 'db_owner', because it does not exist or you do not have permission.

Comment: So server logins have different role settings? 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/security/authentication-access/create-a-server-role?view=sql-server-2017

Comment: Make sure you run these commands (to create user from Login and addrolemember) on your data database and NOT the master db. Only Login creation needs to happen through Master DB.

Comment: I've been creating users for the database inside the server and I know how to do that.  I'm trying to add a login so that that I can access the server using sql server authentication such that the apps I build will connect via Developement username and password.

I think I'm supposed to grant permissions??

Comment: I understand that :) on phone right now so tough to elaborate.. take a look at my answer here.. question is a little different so don’t worry about readonly part.. but see my detailed explanation and commands https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52213706/configuring-azure-db-as-read-only/52215408#52215408

Comment: @Dtjin Are you looking for this development user to get access to all the databases on your db server instead of any specific one?

Comment: Exactly what I am trying to do.  I tried granting the Development user  and ALTER permission last night and I got error 'Grantor does not have GRANT permission.'  Even if this works, I would have to grant other permissions settings.  How do I let development user to get access to all the databases on my db server?